# YouTube HTML5 player presents black screen after seekTo. My bug or YouTube's?

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

UPDATE: Have received no explanation/resolution to this issue and have reported it as a prospective flaw to Google:

https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=3917

I'm working on a site in which I'd like to use YouTube's **HTML5** player to display sections of a video at predefined timestamps. I believe the code works correctly with the Flash player.

For argument's sake, in the referenced video, I wish to display the video at timestamps of 10s and 25s.

I think I'm doing everything correctly. The video is loaded multiple times and, "onReady", the code calls "seekTo" the timecode and then pauses the play.

Here's the code. If you're unfamiliar with JSBin, click "Run with JS" in the upper right hand corner of the "Output" screen to run it.

http://jsbin.com/ereneh/3/edit

I feel as though I've tried all permutations but I'm unable to get the video to display a screenshot of the video at the timestamps. If I manually play the video to the timestamp and then pause, it works (as expected). If I let the code run and then hit "play", the video resumes from the correct timestamp and the image appears seemingly instantly.

Am I using the API incorrectly and/or overlooking something? Is this a bug?

The console shows repeated 404s but these occur once "play" is clicked and there is no evident problem that results; the video plays as expected.

GET http://www.youtube.com/get_video?noflv=1&video_id=vn57vxP4M18&el=embedded&eurl=unknown&fmt=43&ptk=youtube_none&splay=1&start=25000 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Is there any firewall blocking you? It works as expected for me. :)

Comment: Thanks! That was quick! When you say it works as expected, you see the vidoes paused and screenshots? There could be a firewall but shouldn't be. I work from home and don't run any firewall beyond Windows' firewall. Comcast could run something I guess.

Comment: Yes, I do see the paused video with a visible frame

Comment: Oh, and sorry, can you double-check that you're running the HTML5 player not the Flash player. I think it works fine with the Flash player. Right-click on one of the videos... Do you see a menu including "About HTML5"?

Comment: @juan-mendes thanks.The behavior only occurs with the HTML5 player.

Comment: How do you force the HTML5 player?

Comment: @juan-mendes unfortunately, you can't easily. I uninstalled Flash from my machine (for other reasons) and so, by default, get the HTML5 player in IE. In Firefox I get an error "missing plugins". Chrome has the player integrated directly but, it's also easy to switch it on/off using about://plugins and enabling/disabling "Adobe Flash Player"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21541/discussion-between-dazwilkin-and-juan-mendes)